# How can I keep the original format of a cell in an Excel macro?

Tags: excel, vba, email, outlook

I'm new in Excel VBA and I have managed to create a simple macro to automate some e-mails that carry a customized report for people at my work. In this case I'm a using a worksheet that changes depending on the information added to the file in general. The macro uses some of this info and creates a customized e-mail. Some of this info are time and percentage values, and in the worksheet the cells keep that formats. For example, if the person has worked 3 hours in a specific task it will show the cell as "3:00". But when creating the variables and using them to create the e-mail, the values are shown in their numeric counterpart.

> EXAMPLE EMAIL
>
> This is the 0.666666666666667 report! The idea of this automated
>   e-mail is to help you fulfill your daily target expectations. Feel
>   free to contact us if you think something can be done better!
>
> Currently you are sitting in:  •  00:00 of Rating Time •  00:00 of
>   Quality Time •    2.79282407407407E-02 of Not Rating Time Since now it is
>   0.666666666666667, you should have 0.3125, so you are missing 0.284571759259259. Also, your daily completion target is now at 0.133333333333333. PD: you have 00:00 so you are perfect!.

I would like to show this values in the specific format that I need, which is the original format of the cells also. I leave you the code, sorry if there are rookie mistakes, I'm new to this. Thanks in advance.

```
Sub SendEmail(what_address As String, subject_line As String, email_body As String)

Dim olApp As Outlook.Application
Set olApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

    Dim olMail As Outlook.MailItem
    Set olMail = olApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)

    olMail.To = what_address
    olMail.Subject = subject_line
    olMail.BodyFormat = olFormatHTML
    olMail.HTMLBody = email_body
    olMail.Send

End Sub
Sub SendMassEmail()

row_number = 1

Do
DoEvents

    'Adding 1 to the counter

    row_number = row_number + 1

    'Creating the variables

    Dim mail_body_message As String
    Dim full_name As String
    Dim rating As String
    Dim quality_review As String
    Dim not_rating_time As String
    Dim inactive As String
    Dim absolute_target As String
    Dim missing As String
    Dim inactive_comment As String
    Dim expected_time As String
    Dim hour As String
    Dim recipient As String

    'Define the non-moving elements

    mail_body_message = Sheet10.Range("J2")
    hour = Sheet10.Range("J8")
    expected_time = Sheet10.Range("J11")
    recipient = Sheet10.Range("B" & row_number) & "@accenture.com"

    'Define the moving elements

    full_name = Sheet10.Range("A" & row_number)
    rating = Sheet10.Range("C" & row_number)
    quality_review = Sheet10.Range("D" & row_number)
    not_rating_time = Sheet10.Range("E" & row_number)
    inactive = Sheet10.Range("F" & row_number)
    absolute_target = Sheet10.Range("G" & row_number)
    missing = Sheet10.Range("H" & row_number)
    inactive_comment = Sheet10.Range("I" & row_number)

    'Replacing elements in the email body

    mail_body_message = Replace(mail_body_message, "replace_name", full_name)
    mail_body_message = Replace(mail_body_message, "replace_hour", hour)
    mail_body_message = Replace(mail_body_message, "replace_rating", rating)
    mail_body_message = Replace(mail_body_message, "replace_quality", quality_review)
    mail_body_message = Replace(mail_body_message, "replace_nrt", not_rating_time)
    mail_body_message = Replace(mail_body_message, "replace_expected", expected_time)
    mail_body_message = Replace(mail_body_message, "replace_missing", missing)
    mail_body_message = Replace(mail_body_message, "replace_target", absolute_target)
    mail_body_message = Replace(mail_body_message, "replace_inactive", inactive)
    mail_body_message = Replace(mail_body_message, "replace_inacomment", inactive_comment)


    Call SendEmail(recipient, "DO NOT RESPOND - TEST EMAIL", mail_body_message)

Loop Until row_number = Sheet10.Range("J5")

MsgBox "The e-mails have been sent!"

End Sub
```

Comment: Wherever that happens, wrap the variable in `TEXT()`, i.e. to show just 2.5 instead of 2.50000 or something, do `Text(myvar,"0.0")`,  or say a date, `Text(myvar,"mm/dd/yyyy")`, etc.  See [this page](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/TEXT-function-20d5ac4d-7b94-49fd-bb38-93d29371225c) for more.

Comment: `quality_review = Sheet10.Range("D" & row_number).TEXT`

Answer (score 1):

You are defaulting to the cell .Value property. Specify the .Text property to retrieve what you see in the cell.

```
full_name = Sheet10.Range("A" & row_number).Text
rating = Sheet10.Range("C" & row_number).Text
quality_review = Sheet10.Range("D" & row_number).Text
not_rating_time = Sheet10.Range("E" & row_number).Text
inactive = Sheet10.Range("F" & row_number).Text
absolute_target = Sheet10.Range("G" & row_number).Text
missing = Sheet10.Range("H" & row_number).Text
inactive_comment = Sheet10.Range("I" & row_number).Text
```

You might also declare all of the vars as strings.